# Javascript regex replace with conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regex in JavaScript to replace some words in a multi-line text. 
Origin:

> Doka (1) is 20 years old. Doka, (2) Sole are my friends. Sole told me "Doka (3) is a nice gỉrl!"
>   Doka: (4) student of Hamma school.
>   I met Doka (5) yesterday.

Result of replacement as expected:

> **Bob** (1) is 20 years old. **Bob**, (2) Sole are my friends. Sole told me "Doka (3) is a nice gỉrl!"
>   Doka: (4) student of Hamma school.
>   I met **Bob** (5) yesterday.

In this example, I would want to replace **Doka (1, 2, 5)** with **Bob**. The conditions to replace a match are:

1. Not inside double quotes.
2. Not between a carriage return and a colon.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regular expression and code, provided that any double quotes are properly closed, i.e. they occur an even number of times:

```js
var str = `Doka (1) is 20 years old. Doka, (2) Sole are my friends. Sole told me "Doka (3) is a nice gỉrl!"
Doka: (4) student of Hamma school.
I met Doka (5) yesterday.`;

str = str.replace(/(([^\n\r])Doka|Doka(?!:))(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g, '$2Bob');

console.log(str);
```

#### Explanation:

- `([^\n\r])Doka`: matches "Doka" and the character preceding it, provided that this preceding character is not a line-break character (i.e. neither a linefeed nor a carriage return). That character is captured in a group (parentheses), so we can restore it during the replacement.
- `|Doka(?!:)`: in case the above does not match this alternative will be tried. This happens when there is not any preceding character (i.e. "Doka" appears at the very start), or a line-break character precedes it. In this case we only allow a match when "Doka" is not followed by a colon.

The above two expressions are put in another set of parentheses to set the boundary of the OR (`|`) operation. This becomes the first capture group.

- `(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)`: this requires that a potential match is followed by an even number of quotes up to the very end (`$`) of the string. This comes down to requiring that the match is not wrapped in double quotes.

The replacement string `$2Bob` restores the second capture group (which is what is matched by `[^\n\r]`, and could be nothing at all), and then inserts "Bob".

Comment: @qxz, I have added some explanation.

Comment: Preceding character is not a dot. How to solve this?

Comment: You want to *not* replace when there is a dot before the word? That is exactly the same requirement as that there can be no newline before it, so just add that character to the list, like `[^\n\r.]`. Do you understand this notation? `[^ .... ]`? You can read about regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).